# C# UWP Change image only once with KeyDown

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, keydown

I'm making a silly game for school project and whenever the player moves right or left the image change with the direction. Problem is the image blinks obviously because it keeps changing for same image all the time when clicking. I believe I'd need to change image only on first click but I have no idea how to do it. Any Help? TIA

Here is the method I'm using for KeyDown:

```
private void MoveLeft(Image playerToMove)
    {
        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(playerToMove);
        left -= _step;
        playerToMove.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Characters/ShepherdLeft.png"));
        Canvas.SetLeft(playerToMove, left);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remember what was the previous direction the player moved. Here is some  pseudo-code to help with that:

```
private enum Direction 
{
   Right,
   Left,
   Unknown
}

private Direction lastDirection = Direction.Unknown;

private void MoveLeft(Image playerToMove)
{
  if (lastDirection != Direction.Left)
  {
     playerToMove.Source = "ShepherdLeft.png";
  }
  lastDirection = Direction.Left;
}

private void MoveRight(Image playerToMove)
{
  if (lastDirection != Direction.Right)
  {
     playerToMove.Source = "ShepherdRight.png";
  }
  lastDirection = Direction.Right;
}
```

Comment: In the end I created a Main class for the player with 2 classes with the directions and changed visibility :) But your way is simpler :) ty

double left = Canvas.GetLeft(playerToMove.PlayerLeftAvatar());
            playerToMove.PlayerLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            playerToMove.PlayerRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            left += _step;
            Canvas.SetLeft(playerToMove.PlayerLeftAvatar(), left);
            Canvas.SetLeft(playerToMove.PlayerRightAvatar(), left);